# Android Text to Speech example fails

Tags: android

I'm trying to run the example shown at:

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/TextToSpeechActivity.html

I can build the example fine, install it on my phone [HTC Desire, Android 2.2], run it; however when I press the button, nothing happens; and looking in the logs I find the following:

```
I/TTS received: ( 2877): Howdy
V/TtsService( 2886): TTS service received Howdy
I/TtsService( 2886): Stopping
I/TtsService( 2886): Stopped
V/TtsService( 2886): TTS processing: Howdy
V/TtsService( 2886): TtsService.setLanguage(eng, GBR, )
E/SVOX Pico Engine( 2886): Failed to load textana resource for en-GB [-40]
I/SynthProxy( 2886): setting speech rate to 100
I/SynthProxy( 2886): setting pitch to 100
E/SVOX Pico Engine( 2886): Error synthesizing string 'Howdy': [-101]
```

Any ideas what's happening here? I tried Googling 'SVOX Pico Engine' and 'Failed to load textana resource' but found anything useful.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Settings in you Android Mobile ->  Voice Input and Output -> Text-to-Speech settings -> Click on Install Voice Data ..

This will install the synthesizer